# Moving java web service application from eclipse IDE to real JRE 1.4

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created java web service client application by adding web service using wizard. My JRE is 1.4 and now application is using some eclipse plugins libraries:
[image]

I need to install this application to jeal java 1.4 environment.  I suppose I will need to copy all additional library jar's also. Is that truth? Is it possible, that thees jar's has dependences to others jar's from eclipse plugins?

Comment: You're living at least 13 years in the past. Java 1.4 was born in 2002, Java 1.5 in 2005, and we're expecting the arrival of Java 9. Anyway, just move all your relevant jars inside WEB-INF/lib folder and you'll be ok.

Comment: I agree with @Luiggi Mendoza but I would add that you should check that all your additionnal jars a java 1.4 compliant

Comment: But I think, that if my project JDK in Eclipse is 1.4 and it runs, libs should be compliant